# What is the nature of the multipoles used to shape/re-direct an e-beam?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electrons, dipole, multipole-expansion

Imagine having an electron beam, just like in an electron microscope.

Now imagine that we have some multipoles prepared in the beams path to influence the shape/path of the beam.

My question is: these multipoles are usually only electrostatic aren't they? There is no magnetic component to them.

So in other words I imagine that for example when we have a quad-pole, we'd need 4 metal rods of which we charge 2 negative and 2 positive and place them alternating between negative and positive.

Now these rods should have electrical fields which will influence the incoming beam of electrons.

Are my assumptions correct? Or is there a magnetic component to them which I am missing?

Comment: There are electrostatic and electromagnetic lenses.

Comment: I know but when people talk of di-poles or quad-poles I'd assume that they mean elektrostatic lenses. No?